# Unable to unlocalize a Folder in CMS - Time out exception

Tags: 2013

I am unable to unlocalize a Folder which is at Level 1, where Level 0 is parent Publication. Time out error occurs while trying to unlocalize the Folder.

Is there a preferred timeout setting for such scenarios?

**Time out settings tried**

> Seconds before a time out error is generated when executing a long query
>
> Seconds before a time out error is generated when executing a query

Option 1 : 500 seconds 500 seconds (8 minutes)

Option 2 : 1800 seconds 1800 seconds (30 minutes)
[image]
Option 3 : 14400 seconds 14400 seconds (4 hours)

[image]

Comment: Can you please update the question with the Actual Error from Event Viewer or Logs?

Comment: If it's not `sp_updatestats` , can you stick a TRACE on the SQL database and follow the Stored Proc _EDA_ORG_ITEMS_UNLOCALIZE_ ?

Understanding where it's hanging may help. Can you confirm that you can unlocalize a SG, a PT and CT also (just to complete the fact you've tested Pages and Components).

Answer (score 12):

Actually, timeout exceptions don't always depend on JUST timeout values defined in MMC snap-in console (Tridion Content Manager Config).

Before you start increasing timeouts to insane values, I suggest you verify that your CM database is properly maintained and therefore fast.

To do this, please update statistics and rebuild indexes. Also, you can use purge tool to remove old versions of items.

Comment: Timeout error occurs only for unlocalizing a folder. Un localizing a component or page works just fine. Could it be an issue executing stored procedure, EDA_ORG_ITEMS_UNLOCALIZE.

Comment: +1 to the database mainenance, @user679526 timeout issues usually ALWAYS are related to poor database performance due to out of date statistics on the database.

Comment: I just want to add that that even if from application side your unlocalization is same action for folder as for component, you dont know what happens "under the hood" in database, which procedures are executed. This happened to us also when our database was slow. We could do all actions in tridion except porting items and deleting components. Once we did maintenance, all started flying like Starship Enterprise :)

Answer (score 6):

Timeouts usually indicate that there is a real issue. Increasing the timeout value is just a workaround, and sometimes there is no value large anough to fix the issue. Rather than a workaround, focus on the actual problem. My guess is that your database is not properly maintained and thus not performing well, causing the timeout.

Here are some steps for you to follow in solving that (focussed on MS SQL Server, if you have an Oracle database, contact your DBA):

1. Read the documentation on maintenance of your system, that is your job now (assume it is never done, and it won't be done automatically unless you schedule something) http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-94283420-8A51-4F2C-913E-B18455E58D74
2. The documentation doesn't mention any specifics for MS SQL Server anymore, since that belongs in a standard MS SQL maintenance plan, but a trained DBA knows that there are some tasks he can better perform or schedule manually to keep DB performance up to par. You can read this old DB maintenance guide for some tips http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/MaintainingSDLTridiondatabases.aspx
3. `exec sp_updatestats` is a useful command for MS SQL Server, read up on that. It is the one command I would blindly run on a MS SQL Server Tridion DB and it has performed magical results (the longer it takes to run the first time, the more magic it will give you, as that shows how long it hasn't been run)
4. Truncating your transaction log on your database is the next best thing you can do. Especially for MS SQL Server, if it has never been truncated, chances are it is larger than 1GB which will bring the performance of your database to a standstill.
5. After you are sure the issue can't be caused by your database, i.e. you have performed and scheduled regular maintenance for it, then the next thing you should look into is possible issues on the CM server or the network to it. Is this only occuring for some clients, is it also occuring when the browser is opened on the server itself directly etc.

Comment: +1 on `exec sp_updatestats` - if this hasn't been done on this specific database (and don't assume because it's done on one DB/environment it is on another) this is always the first to check for me (and more often than not - surprisingly - the culprit!!)